# Ionic APK with https

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am building an audio/video chat in ionic framework.
For the A/V to work the https protocol needs to added.
I made all the necessary changes in my client and server for this to happen.
As expected https://localhost to https://server calls are dwelling well and much to my satisfaction, when I run from browser.

I was actually wondering, when I would build the APK via ionic CLI and test it on a real device, would the https (client) be integrated ?
I mean how do I serve the ionic app with https for my A/V to work?

Thanks

Comment: The issue is a bit unclear here. As I read it you are asking if your app will be able to make https calls? the answer is yes, you do not need to do anything to make that happen, but you might want to look into Content-Security-Policys as this might block your calls...

Comment: Hi @iCediCe , sorry for not being so clear on issue. I am able to make https calls.During development phase my client (the browser here) is served over https e.g    <https://>localhost:64332/myapp/#home and i am able to call my APIs which are also served over https. What I wanted to know when I build the app and install it on an android device does the app will also be served over https ? or would that http?

Comment: Ah ok, now I get it. I don't think there is anyway to serve your app over https but it is discussed around the net if you google it. But connecting to https from your http served app does not seem to give any issues, I do this all the time.